# SQL*Plus Spool Oracle ( Subquery /With Clause Issue)

Tags: oracle, csv, sqlplus, spool

Can you please help me ?

when I execute the .sql file below in Toad, it gives me the expected results.

```
 with 
    a as(select extract(year from sysdate)var_year,to_char(sysdate,'mm-dd')var_day from dual),
    b as(select case when var_day between '10-01'and '12-31'
    then to_date(var_year||'-10-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
    else to_date(var_year-1||'-10-01','yyyy-mm-dd')end d1,
    case when var_day between'10-01'and'12-31'
    then to_date(var_year+1||'-09-30','yyyy-mm-dd')
    else to_date(var_year||'-09-30','yyyy-mm-dd')end d2
    from a)
    select * from b,SCHEMA.TABLE1
    where SCHEMA.TABLE1.DATE_FRAIS between b.d1 and b.d2;
```

But when I Try to launch it using a .cmd job adding a spool function, the console opens but nothing happens and the console stay open. The .csv file is generated but nothing inside.

Please find below Script not working (spool succeeded but without content):

```
SET FEEDBACK OFF
set heading on
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET LINESIZE 8000
set pagesize 50000
SET COLSEP ";"
COLUMN dcol new_value mydate noprint
select to_char(sysdate,'YYYY_MM_DD') dcol from dual;
SPOOL test.csv;
with 
a as(select extract(year from sysdate)var_year,to_char(sysdate,'mm-dd')var_day from dual),
b as(select case when var_day between '10-01'and '12-31'
then to_date(var_year||'-10-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
else to_date(var_year-1||'-10-01','yyyy-mm-dd')end d1,
case when var_day between'10-01'and'12-31'
then to_date(var_year+1||'-09-30','yyyy-mm-dd')
else to_date(var_year||'-09-30','yyyy-mm-dd')end d2
from a)
select * from b,SCHEMA.TABLE1
where SCHEMA.TABLE1.DATE_FRAIS between b.d1 and b.d2;
SPOOL OFF
```

Whereas, when I launch a "simple" .SQL file by a .cmd job adding a spool function, it works (maybe because I removed "CASE" ?).The .csv file is generated and there is content inside

Please find below an example of Script working (spool succedeed with content) :

```
    SET FEEDBACK OFF
set heading on
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET LINESIZE 8000
set pagesize 50000
SET COLSEP ";"
COLUMN dcol new_value mydate noprint
select to_char(sysdate,'YYYY_MM_DD') dcol from dual;
SPOOL test.csv;
with
a as (select extract(year from sysdate) var_year1, extract(year from sysdate) var_year2, to_char(sysdate) var_day from dual)
select * from a;
SPOOL OFF
```

Comment: If you run your "non-working" query from the SQL*Plus command line, what do you get?

Comment: How does your .cmd file launch SQL\*Plus and run the script - with @? Does your script have an `exit` at the end?

Comment: Also does your `table1` actually have matching data that you can see from SQL\*Plus - or have you perhaps inserted some through the same Toad session the query works from, and haven't committed? I suspect both issues here - uncommitted data and no exit from the script. More details please. You can also simplify what you're doing quite a bit.

Comment: @Politank-Z :  
If you run your "non-working" query from the SQL*Plus command line => the console opens, and nothing happens, the console stay opend, whereas with a working query, i see the processing of SQL lines.

Comment: @AlexPoole : Cmd launch SQL*plus with this command : sqlplus username/password@databasename @"c:\my_script.sql" .  No, there is not exit at the end. But the issue, is not the the consoel stay opened, but that the lines are not processing in the console like my example working script ( descibed in my initial problem)

Comment: @Ezequiel_075 - your simpler  `a`-only script only refers to sysdate and dual, not to any real data, so it will work anyway. Your main script will only show anything if there is committed, matching data in your table. Please run just that statement in a normal SQL\*Plus session and see if it runs and says 'no rows selected', or actually finds anything.

Comment: @AlexPoole : Yes I will check tommorrow if it is commited for sure, as I tried this script on my test environment, maybe you are right. I have data in production, but maybe not in Test

Comment: @AlexPoole, thanks you very much indeed, it was not commited on my trial environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that (a) you've run this as `sqlplus -s user/pass @script` and don't have an `exit` at the end of your script, which will cause the command window to stay open; and (b) you don't have any committed data in your table for this year's date range. You would see that effect if you added data in your Toad session and ran your query there, but did not commit those changes - the newly-inserted data would not be visible to any other session in that case, so your SQL*Plus query wouldn't see it. And since you have feedback off, you wouldn't even see 'no rows selected`.

---

@boneist's simplification is cleaner and simpler than mine, but I'll leave this to show the CTE and non-CTE, and the `between` and `>=`/`<` variations.

Incidentally, you can simplify your date calculation quite a bit, to something like:

```
with b as (
  select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY'),
      case when extract(month from sysdate) < 10 then -3 else 9 end) d1,
    last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY'),
      case when extract(month from sysdate) < 10 then 8 else 20 end)) d2
  from dual
)
select *
from b
join table1 on table1.date_frais between b.d1 and b.d2;
```

You can see the start and end dates the CTE would generate for various dates with [this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/1426). I think that's what you're after, if I've [interpreted your current query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/1429) properly. (And [here is the same query with @boneist's simplification](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/1548)).

Or if you don't really want to show the date range as well as the actual data from `table1`, move the calculation into the filter:

```
select * -- but still better to list the columns
from table1
where date_frais >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY'),
      case when extract(month from sysdate) < 10 then -3 else 9 end)
and date_frais < add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY'),
      case when extract(month from sysdate) < 10 then 9 else 21 end);
```

I've also changed this version from `between` to use `>=` and `<`, and pushed the end-date out by a day; that will include any values on the last day of the final month which have a time after midnight (which I see @boneist also commented on). If your dates are all midnight then `between` would work, but I still prefer this explicit pattern, and it makes the month adjust calculation a little more obvious too I think.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be simply that your query takes a long time to retrieve all the results, and you haven't left it long enough? You might see results in Toad, but have you tried going to the end of the resultset, rather than just getting the first 500 rows (or however many you have set Toad to retrieve per fetch).

I doubt the issue is anything to do with the `WITH` clause. In any case, there is no need for it; you can simply manipulate sysdate like so, in order to get your results:

```
select *
from   SCHEMA.TABLE1 t1
where  t1.DATE_FRAIS between add_months(trunc(add_months(sysdate, 3), 'yyyy'), -3) 
                     and     add_months(trunc(add_months(sysdate, 3), 'yyyy'), 9) -1;
```

N.B. I hope your DATE_FRAIS column has no time elements to it, otherwise you'll be missing anything that's after midnight on the 30th September of each year.

Comment: Thinking rather alike, at least in terms of simplification; but the OP's range covers different years depending on the current month, so a query run in November would cover Oct 15 to Sep 16, which you aren't handling. And the OP is also including the `b` columns in the select list with `*`, though not sure if that's entirely intentional... but without a CTE you'd need to repeat the calculation if they are needed.

Comment: My calculation works as expected; have you tried replacing sysdate with a date in November? And as for the columns appearing in the select - if that's what the OP wants, I agree that a CTE would be the best way of handling it, but it could just be selecting the above two date calculations, rather than the case statements the OP used originially.

Comment: Ha, no, despite demo'ing the OP's version and my version I didn't try yours for some reason. I totally missed the nested add_months doing that adjustment, much neater than my way of doing it (and more subtle...). Sorry, you're [quite right, of course](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/1548). Well, I can't upvote again, sadly.

Comment: I love date arithmetic *{:-) (note, that's _date_ arithmetic. _timestamp_ arithmetic can go take a long walk off a short pier as far as I'm concerned!)